# Highchart x-axis shuffle randomly even the data is proper

Tags: python, node.js, highcharts, python-pptx

[image]

We have implemented ppt download feature with python-pptx including highcharts init.
But the X-axis values are shuffling randomly, Even the data encountered is proper.

Current output X-axis: 29-feb, 31-jan, 31-dec
Required output X-axis: 31-Oct, 30-Nov,31-Dec,..and so on
(data is dynamic, we cant make axis values fix)

```
def create_column_clustered_comparison_payload(slide_layout, input_chart_data, chart_width, chart_height, enable_3d):
column_clustered_comparison = { "infile": {
        "title": {
            "text": None
        },
        "chart": {},
        "xAxis": {
            "lineColor": "#000000",
            "lineWidth": 1,
            "tickLength": 0,
            "gridLineWidth": 0,
            "title": {
                "text": None
            },
            "labels": {
                "style": {
                    "fontSize": "9px",
                    "color": "#000000"
                },
                "padding": 0
            }
        },
        "yAxis": [{
            "title": {
                "text": None
            },
            "lineColor": "#000000",
            "lineWidth": 1,
            "gridLineWidth": 0,
            "labels": {
                "style": {
                    "fontSize": "9px",
                    "color": "#000000"
                },
                "padding": 0,
                "format": "{value}%"
            }
        }, {
            "title": {
                "text": None
            },
            "lineColor": "#000000",
            "lineWidth": 1,
            "opposite": True,
            "gridLineWidth": 0,
            "labels": {
                "style": {
                    "fontSize": "9px",
                    "color": "#000000"
                },
                "padding": 0
            }
        }],
        "plotOptions": {
            "column": {
                "grouping": True,
                "shadow": False,
                "dataLabels": {
                    "enabled": True,
                    "style": {
                      "fontSize": "10px",
                      "fontWeight": False
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "legend": {
            "enabled": True,
            "itemStyle": {
                "color": "#000000",
                "fontSize": "9px",
                "fontWeight": None
            },
            "itemMarginTop": 5,
            "itemMarginBottom": 20
        },
        "credits": {
            "enabled": False
        },
        "series": [{
            "type": "column",
            "borderWidth": 0,
            "color": "#29336a"
        }, {
            "type": "column",
            "borderWidth": 0,
            "color": "#b8c4ff"
        }, {
            "type": "spline",
            "color": "#ffab3d",
            "lineWidth": 2,
            "marker": {
                "lineWidth": 2,
                "lineColor": "#747578",
                "fillColor": "white",
                "radius": 2.5
            }
        }]
    }
}

chart_keys = list(input_chart_data.keys())
categories = [category for category in input_chart_data[chart_keys[0]]['data'].keys()]
column_clustered_comparison['infile']['xAxis']['categories'] = categories

index = 0
for key in chart_keys:

    chart_type = input_chart_data[key]['type']
    if chart_type == 'bar':

        index += 1
        if index == 2:

            column_clustered_comparison['infile']['series'][1]['name'] = key
            column_clustered_comparison['infile']['series'][1]['data'] = \
                [input_chart_data[key]['data'][category] for category in categories]
            continue

        column_clustered_comparison['infile']['series'][0]['name'] = key
        column_clustered_comparison['infile']['series'][0]['data'] = \
            [input_chart_data[key]['data'][category] for category in categories]

    elif chart_type == 'line':
        column_clustered_comparison['infile']['series'][2]['name'] = key
        column_clustered_comparison['infile']['series'][2]['data'] = \
            [input_chart_data[key]['data'][category] for category in categories]
        column_clustered_comparison['infile']['series'][2]['yAxis'] = 1

if chart_width:
    column_clustered_comparison['infile']['chart']['width'] = 570
if chart_height:
    column_clustered_comparison['infile']['chart']['height'] = 280

return column_clustered_comparison
```

Comment: Can you add your code to help reproduce your problem?

Comment: Are you sure that the x data which you are pasting is proper? Have you tested it in milliseconds how it would look like in the UTC? https://currentmillis.com/

Comment: Yes, in console, the data is in sequence. and even if I am sending dummy data, it shuffles.

Comment: What is the `python-pptx` code you use to produce the chart? This is a multiple-plot chart which is not yet supported by the `python-pptx` API.